# How to make java application run all the time on webserver

Tags: java, ftp

I have made a simple **java application** that merges 100 txt files to 1 "mega.txt"
Those files are on an ftp server(my friend's pc using filezilla server). My application downloads those files and replace the "mega.txt" with the new merged one...
My question: is there any way to upload my app on a server and run to do the job **alone** away from my pc **all the time**?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Run it as a daemon thread on the server.  If you implement it using Java 7 and the new file system watching feature you'll have a nice solution.

Comment: My knowledge stop after i upload my .jar file to server...
On my pc my application run all the time but how if i want to run on server all time what have i had to do?